# html/jquery - submitting a form in iframe

Tags: html, jquery, iframe

I have a form which has an iframe as target. It works well when using the classic "submit" button, but when I use Jquery to submit the form, it opens a new window and does not target in the iframe. Any suggestion on why this happens?
Here is my code:

```
function formSubmit() {
  $('#formId').submit();
}
<form name="formId" id="formId" action="ajax/submitForm.php" method="post" target="iframe_submit" tmt:validate="true">
   [...]
   <input type="button" id="submit_button" value="GO" onclick="javascript:formSubmit();" />
</form>

<iframe style="border:none;width:0px;height:0px" id="iframe_submit" name="iframe_submit"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
 $('#formId').get(0).submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem not in iframe but in `onclick="javascript:formSubmit();"`. For start you don't need to write `javascript:` in `on..=""` attributes. But better to use jQuery events:

```
<form name="formId" id="formId" action="ajax/submitForm.php" method="post" target="iframe_submit">
    <input type="text" name="x" />
   <input type="button" id="submit_button" value="GO" />
</form>
```

and:

```
function ftformSubmit() {
  $('#formId').submit();
}
$(function(){
    $('#submit_button').click(function(){
        $('#formId').submit();
    });
});
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/narekmarkosyan/EUFhs/)

Comment: tried this too, but it doesn't work. I tried also with "bind('click',function)" and nothing. I can't really understand

Comment: It works in fiddle I gave. If doesn't work for you then problem in other place.

Comment: Yes, I see it works, I'm trying to understand if there are other errors in the page...thank you

Comment: there was a php error in the page with some code added together with the code posted here. the code written under the line with the error was not loaded, so the iframe was missing. sorry for wasting your time, I've asked the closing of this useless post...